# Why doesn't this simple for loop work as expected?

Tags: javascript, loops

One might expect the following to print out `a`, `b`, `c`.

```
var i, rowName;
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++, rowName = ['a', 'b', 'c'][i]) {
    console.log(rowName);
}
```

Instead, however, it prints out `undefined`, `b`, `c`. Why?

To clarify: I know how to make this work; what I'm curious about is *why* the above doesn't work.

Comment: The final expression is only evaluated at the *end* of each loop iteration. `rowName` is undefined before then. See [for @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Comment: The 3rd (and 2nd) expression in the `for` loop isn't evaluated until the end of each iteration. If it were evaluated upfront to assign `rowName`, it would also immediately increment `i` to `1`, skipping the initial value of `0`.

Comment: The documentation could hardly be clearer. It says "final-expression
An expression to be evaluated **at the end of each loop iteration**. This occurs before the next evaluation of condition. Generally used to update or increment the counter variable."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it prints `undefined`, `b`, `c` is because of how a [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) works.

```
for (initialization; condition; final expression)
```

Let's break down your for loop.

*initialization*: `i = 0`

*condition*: `i < 3`

*final expression*: `i++, rowName = ['a', 'b', 'c'][i]`

When your loop is first entered, `i` is set to `0`. This is the initialization step. Then the *condition* step, `i < 3`, is checked. This is done before every iteration to decide whether or not to continue looping. After each loop, the *final expression* is evaluated. In your example, you increment `i` before setting `rowName` equal to an element in `['a', 'b', 'c']` based on the current index.

In your case, on the first iteration, `rowName` is `undefined` because the *final expression* is yet to be evaluated. Every iteration thereafter behaves as you would expect since a final expression has already been previously evaluated.

Comment: "In your example, you increment `i` before setting `rowName`". True, but what does incrementing `i` have to do with assignment of `rowName`? Misleading.

Comment: @PHPglue How is that misleading? I did not say either has anything to do with the other. However, both statements happen to be "final expressions," or "post-loop operations", and are hence both evaluated after each loop.

Comment: It might confuse OP into thinking that matters.

Comment: @PHPglue Into thinking what matters?

Comment: Incrementing `i` before setting `rowName` has nothing to do with the fact that the third part of the for loop doesn't execute until the first pass is complete. It just makes `i` start with `1` on the second pass.

Comment: @PHPglue hence why I say `In your case, on the first iteration, rowName is undefined because the final expression is yet to be evaluated.` at the beginning of the next paragraph. Either way, what would you rephrase so as to make my answer less "misleading"?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do the tricky one-line for loop style, the "correct" syntax is:

```
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
for (var i = 0, rowName; rowName = array[ i++ ]; ) {
    console.log(rowName);
}
```

Notice the ending `;` of the `for` loop declaration. There's technically an empty statement after the `;` which is where you normally would do `i++`.

In this case, the "condition" of the for loop is taking advantage of the Javascript assignment operator. If you have some code like this:

```
var a;
if( a = 1 ) { // Note this is assignment = not comparison ==
    console.log('true');
}
```

It **will** log "true". Why? Because inside of an expression, `a = 1` actually returns `1`. And `1` is "truthy," meaning it evaluates to true in a boolean context like an `if` statement.

The opposite is also true, if your value is falsey:

```
var a;
if( a = 0 ) {
    console.log('true');
}
```

It will not log, because `a = 0` is returning 0 (as well as assigning 0 to `a`). And 0 is falsey.

This whacky for-loop syntax is only for certain conditions:

- If any of the array elements are "falsey" (`null`, `undefined`, `""`, etc) it will prematurely terminate the loop, because of how operators work as mentioned above.
- This assumes you don't care about the loop index `i`. It will be off by 1 for every iteration of the loop, because `i++` is executed **before** the `for` block. That is, the first time your `for` body executes, `i` will be 1, not its declared starting value of 0.
- The only benefit of this pattern is saving a few bytes. It's generally not used in the real world because of the above two pitfalls.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this?

```
var i, rowName;
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    rowName = ['a', 'b', 'c'][i];
    console.log(rowName);
}
```

Comment: Because the assignment to `rowname` happens after each execution of the loop. So the first time through, `rowname` has not been assigned, hence you get `undefined`. (You could move the assignment to the "middle" expression in your `for` loop header.)

Answer (score 0):

You are reassigning `rowName` at each step of the loop and it's `undefined` to begin with. Here's what you can do:

```
for(var i=0,rowName=['a','b','c'],l=rowName.length; i<l; i++){
  console.log(rowName[i]);
}
```

or something like:

```
var rowName = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
for(var i=0,l=rowName.length; i<l; i++){
  console.log(rowName[i]);
}
```

The real issue is that the third condition inside `for(assign; test; execute)` does not `execute` until until one `test` of the loop is satisfied. If the `test` fails `execute` never happens. If the `test` passes `execute` really begins after the first pass of the loop.

Comment: The OP's snippet is attempting to log each value individually. While this would log the array, in its entirety, each iteration.